# how to set MATLABPATH in Python and using mlabwrap?

Tags: python, matlab, mlabwrap

I tried to use `mlab.path(path,'/my/path')` but failed. Got `NameError: name 'path' is not defined` in python. Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind. I found out how. Use `mlab.addpath()`.